# How to specify float32 limits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, compilation, constants, literals

Kinda stupid question but I can't get this to compile in JavaScript:

```
var float_MaxValue = 3.40282347e+38F; // largest positive number in float32
var float_MinValue = -3.40282347e+38F; // largest negative number in float32
var float_Eplison = 1.175494351e-38F; // smallest number in float32
```

How do I convert the literals into decimal/hex syntax or whatever compiles? Do you know how to get this to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the "F" at the end

```
var float_MaxValue = 3.40282347e+38; // largest positive number in float32
var float_MinValue = -3.40282347e+38; // largest negative number in float32
var float_Eplison = 1.175494351e-38; // smallest number in float32
```

Tried it in Chrome and it seems to work.

Comment: is 38 in hex or decimal? because 38 in hex is 56 in decimal... so in JS do I need to write 38 or 56?

Comment: its decimal. Try for example "A" instead of "38" and you will get an error.

Comment: I know its decimal in JS, but that snippet was extracted from C++, and specifically postfixed with "F", indicating that it might be hex, am I right? (38F) .. so shouldnt we write 56 in decimal for JS?

Comment: Answer this question and I'll accept your answer. I'm just asking if I should use 38 or 56 in JS.

Comment: As far as I know the "f" in C/C++ stands for "float". If you want to have the smalles/largest possible 32bit float value you need to use 38 in Javascript. (Since I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish: if you want to have the smalles/largest number in javascript you can use Number.MIN_VALUE and Number.MAX_VALUE, but that's not a 32bit value)